# Update ADO Recordset for a Calculated Field

Tags: sql-server, vb6, ado, recordset

I'm using the following sql for an ADO recordset against a SQLServer backend in VB6:

```
select c.name, taxid=
   case when exists(select 1 from sometable where fld='abc') 
   then c.SSN else null end
```

When I try to update the taxid field in a row within the recordset locally ADO complains with the error "Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value."  I assume it's bothered by the fact that the taxid field is coming from a calculated field and not a raw table column. For my purposes I'm never going to be persisting these changes back to the database so I'm looking for a way to tell ADO that have no intent to persist changes so that it will allow me to change the data locally.

Comment: I would expect an error, since taxid isn't a real column. Same error when the output is `taxid = c.name + c.SSN`. Personally I wouldn't be using a recordset in VB6 to persist updates back to the database, but rather use a stored procedure and send parameterized calls to that stored procedure. The procedure would need to be written, of course, to only permit input for updateable columns. I don't know if there's a way to make ADO obey the underlying definition.

Comment: thx @Aaron but I'm not persisting updates back to the database. I'm only trying to alter values in the recordset for my local needs.  Would there be a way to configure the recordset so that ADO isn't "worried" about persistence problems that will never happen?

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the recordset? Set rst.ActiveConnection = Nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think that @HK1's suggestion is a good one, though I'm not sure what happens to your ability to alter any of the values in the recordset whether the column you're trying to update is computed or not. It's been a long time since I played with classic ADO but if the recordset is disconnected it may become read only at that point.

But if you have no interest in using the recordset to perform updates, and you need to alter values locally, perhaps you should consider storing the results in a local array first? That way you can minimize the locking and cursor options of the recordset, for example, and immediately close the recordset and free up those resources.

```
rs.Open cmd, conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

Dim MyArray
MyArray = rs.GetRows()

rs.Close: set rs = nothing
```

Now you can manipulate `MyArray` however you want...

Comment: This got erroneously downvoted, then I got a phone call. Now SO won't let me undo it until you make an edit.

Comment: Oops, done. I need to get off the darned phone here while surfing!

Comment: I was just kidding. :-) Already hit my cap today anyway. Cheers.